# how to set preload for plyr-react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using plyr-react to show the audio. However, I encounter the problem is that the audio will always load content from my server and I don't like that. I want to set attribute preload="none" with the library but it doesn't have this option. What should I do to get the result? Thank you.

```
    <Plyr
      ref={ref}
      source={{
        type: "audio",
        sources: [
          {
            type: "audio/wav",
            src: audioLink,
          },
        ],
      }}
      options={{
        controls: ["play", "progress", "current-time", "volume", "settings"],
        autoplay: false,
      }}
    />
```